# Google Translate Activity not working anymore

Tags: android, android-intent, google-translate

I wrote a program that invokes Google Translator android application via `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`.
The problem is that invoking the Google Translator App does not work anymore, although it did once.

The code is identical to the code given here:

[Returning Translated Text from Google Translate Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082118/returning-translated-text-from-google-translate-activity)

(yes, I tried to replace my code by that code, the Google Translator App behaves as if it does not receive any data.)

Currently I cannot specify the text and the two languages. The best I can do is to use `ACTION_SEND`, but it ignores the two languages:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "What is going on?");
        i.putExtra("key_text_input", "What time is it?");
        i.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
        i.putExtra("key_language_from", "en");
        i.putExtra("key_language_to", "es");
        i.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
        i.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.translate",
            "com.google.android.apps.translate.translation.TranslateActivity"));
```

What actually happened when I ran this code was: the Google Translator asked me if I want to translate from English and  translated "What is going on?" to French.

So: how do I pass the languages to the Google Translate App now?

Answer (score 13):

They have changed it once again:

```
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");

            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
```

UPDATE: It ***is*** possible to pass the languages if you pack the text and the languages into an URI:

```
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");

            Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                    .scheme("http")
                    .authority("translate.google.com")
                    .path("/m/translate")
                    .appendQueryParameter("q", "c'est l'meunier Mathurin qui caresse les filles au tic-tac du moulin")
                    .appendQueryParameter("tl", "pl") // target language
                    .appendQueryParameter("sl", "fr") // source language
                    .build();
            //intent.setType("text/plain"); //not needed, but possible
            intent.setData(uri);
```

Comment: Thanks.. tried all the previous solutions and they didn't work, it's frustrating that they keep on changing the API and very much thanks for keep updating us!!

Comment: The only solution that actually works is using that uri.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

The following code works with the new version of Google Translate Application:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "What is going on?");
        i.putExtra("key_text_input", "Oh my God! What is going on here?");
        //i.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
        i.putExtra("from", "en");
        i.putExtra("to", "zh-CN");
        //i.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
        //i.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.translate",
                "com.google.android.apps.translate.HomeActivity"));
```

As you can see, this is the standard ACTION_SEND with additional parameters "to" and "from".

There's a gotcha: "key_text_input" takes preference over Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, and "to" and "from" work only with "key_text_input".

If you have an impression that no data is passed (at all), maybe it is because you use 3-character language codes instead of 2-character ones. But the codes for Chinese are zh-CN and zh-TW.

My previous post:

The action and the parameter names have changed.

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.google.android.apps.translate.action.QUERY");
        i.putExtra("key_text_input", "Oh my God! What is going on?");
        i.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
        i.putExtra("from", "en");
        i.putExtra("to", "zh-CN");
        i.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
        i.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
        i.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.translate",
            "com.google.android.apps.translate.translation.TranslateActivity"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will open Google Translate app as a full-screen activity. I wanted to open it as a floating window above my current app.

Turns out you can do this with the Intent action of "android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" e.g.

```
translateIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
    "com.google.android.apps.translate",
    "com.google.android.apps.translate.QuickTranslateActivity"
));
translateIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
translateIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, textToTranslate);
```

Note: I didn't actually use this method as I pulled the intent of the system context menu using onActionStarted but I sniffed the intent for you so I don't see why this wouldn't work if created manually.

Comment: I have been using this, but how to specify input/output language? The "from" or "key_language_from" do not seem to work. There is no official documentation for this calling intent and one has to "sniff" the intent to figure out the supported parameters?

Comment: Got ```android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.apps.translate/com.google.android.apps.translate.QuickTranslateActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?``` on device with Android 12