# Access Google Translate App through intents in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-logcat, google-translate

I am developing an Android application where I am invoking the Google Translate app via Intents. The procedure described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132441/google-translate-activity-not-working-anymore) was really helpful but I cannot figure out why my app crashes saying "No Activity found to handle Intent".

Thanks in Advance!

Here is my code,

```
public void translate()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
    intent.putExtra("key_text_input", "hello");
    intent.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
    intent.putExtra("key_language_from", "en");
    intent.putExtra("key_language_to", "mal");
    intent.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
    intent.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
            new ComponentName(
                "com.google.android.apps.translate",
                "com.google.android.apps.translate.HomeActivity");
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

And this is what my logcat shows

```
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3349)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3584)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3552)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at com.example.arch.vaani.ocr.FinalActivity.translate(FinalActivity.java:122)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at com.example.arch.vaani.ocr.FinalActivity$1.onClick(FinalActivity.java:101)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-20 07:29:01.647: E/AndroidRuntime(31465):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where u are calling `intent.setComponent` ?

Comment: Check if Google Translate is installed in your device ?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20321335/1983018. It worked.

Comment: @OP Check out the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088337/2102748

Comment: This answer worked great for me, if you want to use the pop-up translation fragment of google: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825911/9242141

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I tried  the code with a Google Translate App and it is not working.
You may have to use the [Translate API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2) which is a paid service.

Comment: @Chaythanya nair consider changing the accepted answer to the one below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088337/2102748) as basically the only thing that was wrong with your code is the activity name.

Comment: The translate app is now working as expected with the code snippet from the linked answer above ^

Answer (score 13):

You need to change `HomeActivity` to `TranslateActivity`

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
   intent.putExtra("key_text_input", "hello");
   intent.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
   intent.putExtra("key_language_from", "en");
   intent.putExtra("key_language_to", "mal");
   intent.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
   intent.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
   intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
        "com.google.android.apps.translate",
        //Change is here 
        //"com.google.android.apps.translate.HomeActivity")); 
        "com.google.android.apps.translate.TranslateActivity"));
   startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sorry, No Google Translation Installed",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`No Activity found to handle Intent` means that no `Intent` match the `Intent` you started and no `Google Translation App` is installed on your device. So you had better try-catch `ActivityNotFoundException` when you start this `Intent` in case of scenes like this.
Codes are here:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello");
    intent.putExtra("key_text_input", "hello");
    intent.putExtra("key_text_output", "");
    intent.putExtra("key_language_from", "en");
    intent.putExtra("key_language_to", "mal");
    intent.putExtra("key_suggest_translation", "");
    intent.putExtra("key_from_floating_window", false);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.google.android.apps.translate",
            "com.google.android.apps.translate.HomeActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sorry, No Google Translation Installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

At last, **Google Translate API is available as a paid service.**. Check [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).

Comment: I don't  think the Translate App is still working even if you have the app installed.

Comment: tried `intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.google.android.apps.translate",
            "com.google.android.apps.translate.HomeActivity"));`? you didn't set the `ComponentName` on your `Intent` even.

Comment: I tried that too. and old package name. not working. have you tried it?

Comment: If these codes don't work still, you have to re-read its `API`, I think.

Comment: I think that is intentional, Google wants the user of the API to use the paid service. ;) See the link in my posted answer to this question.

Comment: See [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs). **Google Translate API is available as a paid service**

Comment: what is  your point? as I have said, using the Google Translate App via an intent in Android will not work anymore as Google want us to use the paid service via the Translate API. So the package name that was used before may not be available for other apps to use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75668/discussion-between-silentknight-and-christian).