# Android "Google Translation" popup programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-translate

Do you know that **Google Translate** now works inside any app on Android?

I'd like to get rid of extra action in my *app: copy text and press "translate button"*.

Instead of it I'd like to show this popup window using java code. Is it possible?

Comment: any thing got yet?i need same for my app

Answer (score 4):

too late, may be useful for anyone regarding this question...
its working for me

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent .setType("text/plain");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, text);
        }else{
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        }

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)) {

            if( resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.contains("com.google.android.apps.translate")){
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                        resolveInfo.activityInfo.name));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
```

[here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/10/in-app-translations-in-android.html) is the referance...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: In recent Android versions, it needs a permission to read package names. This code does not work unless you add the following to the manifest:  <queries>
  <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.translate"/>
 </queries>

Comment: Comment by @DamnVegetables is good, but I want to add more to that. 1) The queries tag is needed if you target Android 11 (API level 30) or higher: [Package visibility filtering on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility). 2) If you want to use another or different providers, check out Microsoft Translator (com.microsoft.translator) and Reverso Context (com.softissimo.reverso.context).

Comment: Still can not run it even with ```<query>``` defined in ```manifest```

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but...

```
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT);
   intent.setType("text/plain");
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT_READONLY, true);
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT, "hello");
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Sergie, I tried this, however, it is saying no matches found on dictionary pop up. Please help.

Comment: @samirprogrammer, it works, your message might tell you mobile device doesn't have any translation software installed (at least no one which has ```intent-filter``` for ```ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT```).

Comment: Personally I am looking for a way to automatically translate my word without show ```TranslateActivity``` to a user. I haven't found yet a solution with ```Google translate app```, but you might want to use ML kit - it allows out-of-the-box translate text from images. Converting text to image for translation might look awkward, but at least it is a solution you might get right now without extra expenditure on ```Google translate API```