# How to show Google Translate popup from my app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-translate, basic4android

Is it possible to call Google Translate popup (only the popup, and not the whole Google Translate app) from my application, using intent or something else?
I'm using B4A (Basic for Android) platform, so if it is possible, please guide me based on B4A. However Java solutions can be useful too and they are also welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: did you find out a solution to start Google Translate app as popup (not fullscreen)?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/55825911/9242141 worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Translate api in php and call it from b4a

Comment: Good idea, but it isn't perfect for me. In my opinion, Google Translate API has some drawbacks comparing to Google Translate App or Google Translate web (translate.google.com). I'm interested in using Google Translate Application because I think it have better and more complete features.

Comment: Try to install Google Translator and use it with intent

Comment: I've tried this. It performs well. But only one thing that I don't like : Google Translate App covers up the whole screen. It covers my app too! I would like it to be shown in a custom height (and not full screen). If it would be possible to adjust the height of the Google Translate app, it will solve my issue. In addition, the Translate popup doesn't show in full screen, but I can't call it from my app.

Comment: Is it possible to show Google Translate app in a panel, using intent?

Comment: No it isn't possible.
I had searched about show Google Translator in app,but i didn't found any topic about it

Comment: OK. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: The translate app is meant to run as an independent app, and would normally take the whole screen. In fact, Translation API is what you need, it is in fact designed for exactly what you intend to do in your app.

Comment: @George many dictionary apps can be started as popups from other apps, for example we can open card for word we add to intent, take a look at GoldenDict, ColorDict and so on