# How to transform java intent to tasker intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, tasker

I'm looking for an android intent to translate text, and i found this:
[Google Translate Activity not working anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19132441/google-translate-activity-not-working-anymore#)

But i want to use it in tasker. I don't really know java, so i would really like to "translate" that into a tasker intent in the form:

```
Action:
Cat:
Mime Type: 
Data:
Extra: 
Extra: 
Package: 
Class: 
Target:
```

I'll really appreciate any help.
Regards,

Comment: Sorry, I think your question is too broad. We help with specific problems; not with a generic "me vision, but no idea; please fill the gap" request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Java to do it.

Tasker has Intents support built-in, so how about:

```
Translate (27)
A1: Variable Set [ Name:%source_lng To:en Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A2: Variable Set [ Name:%target_lng To:nl Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A3: Variable Set [ Name:%text To:just testing Do Maths:Off Append:Off ] 
A4: Send Intent [ Action:android.intent.action.VIEW Cat:Browsable Mime Type: Data:http://translate.google.com/m/translate?client=ob&hl=en&ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&sl=%source_lng&tl=%target_lng&q=%text Extra: Extra: Extra: Package:com.google.android.apps.translate Class:com.google.android.apps.translate.TranslateActivity Target:Activity ]
```

the `send intent` action can be found in the `system` category

Comment: But how do i save the output?